# jQuery Trigger a click on mouseOut

Tags: jquery, triggers

I have tabs setup, Which animate on hover. What I want to do is on mouseOut, Trigger a click on the tab that has the class of "home".

My current jQuery is as follows :

```
$('div.vertical_tabs ul.st_tabs li a').hover(
        function() {
            $(this).trigger('click');
        }, function() {
            $(this).trigger('click');
});
```

The class I'd like to trigger on mouseOut is : **div.vertical_tabs ul.st_tabs li a.home**

Is this possible?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hiya **demo** http://jsfiddle.net/g97D8/ **or** http://jsfiddle.net/g97D8/1/

for mouse out you can use `mouseout` event.

Please let me know if I am missing anything.

**Jquery code**

```
$('.tag').mouseout(function() {
         alert('foo');
            $('.tag1').trigger('click');

});​
```